# Empty test suite in Android studio Run Test with coverage

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, junit, android-testing

I write some test and want to get code coverage with IntelliJ Plugin!
My test code:

```
public class TestLogin extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<ActivityAccounting> {

private Solo solo;

public TestLogin() {
    super(ActivityAccounting.class);
}

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    solo = new Solo(this.getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}

@Test
public void testLoginClick() throws Exception {
    //Some UI test
}
}
```

In `EditConfiguration` I added a Junit Test:

[image]

But when I run with coverage I code below error:

[image]

What should I do?
tnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have config everything right in build.gradle, something like this:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0'
    //....
    //....
}
```

You only have to run your tests by clicking mouse right-button in your test class and selecting Run

Comment: I add this dependencies before and also my test running well but i can't get test code coverage! do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you running it as JUnit Test?

Comment: Yes. I add a junit test as shown in question in EditConfiguration named "Unnamed" and run this JUnit Test.

Comment: Instead of using this unit test follow the last step I put as answer.

Comment: Check this link, last question https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium/wiki/Questions-&-Answers